# Matlab: Epipolar lines in what coordinate system?

Tags: math, computer-vision, matlab, matlab-cvst

Basically, I have a point in one image (in pixel coordinates) and the corresponding epiline in the other image as given by Matlab's epipolarLine() function (I also have all intrinisics, extrinsics, fundamental matrices). Additionally, I know exactly which row in that image the corresponding point lies--thus, mathematically it is possible to find the matching point by intersecting the row with the epiline. However, I am very confused about the different coordinate systems involved and am mixing them up.

I tried using the integer row value as x in the epipolar line Ax+By+C=0 and solved for y, but I got a decimal answer (decimal part in range of .3-.6, so rounding doesn't make sense). Shouldn't the corresponding y value be an integer as well?

However, I don't know what coordinate system the epipolar lines  are in. Does Matlab return the lines in pixel coordinates, the second camera coordinates, or in first camera coordinates? Furthermore, does (x,y) in pixel coordinates correspond to (row, col) or (col,row) in the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The epipolar lines are defined in the image coordinates in pixels. If you take a look at the example in the [documentation for epipolarLine](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/epipolarline.html) you will see that line equations are defined in pixels.

`(x,y)` corresponds to `(col, row)`. See the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/gs/coordinate-systems.html) for more info. So if you know the row of the corresponding point, that would be the `y` value, not `x`. It seems you have a bug there.

As far as the fractional location you are getting, there is absolutely nothing wrong with that. Think of it this way: you have a 3D world point, which happens to project onto a 2D point in image 1 with integer coordinates. Nothing says that the corresponding 2D point in image 2 must also have integer coordinates.  In fact, it is extremely unlikely that a 3D point would project to 2D points with integer coordinates in both images.

Out of curiosity, how do you know the row of the corresponding point?

Comment: Thanks so much! It makes sense now. For the row index, I'm processing [structured light](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured-light_3D_scanner) scans using [Gray codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code). In short, by decoding stripe patterns from the projector (modeled as the second camera in a stereo system) I can correspond well-lit pixels from the first camera to rows in the "second camera". Then I can intersect the rows with epipolar lines to get pair matches and then triangulate (but I didn't know how the coordinates matched).